# Pandas groupby() .sum() returning row value more than once instead of sum

Tags: python, pandas

I used groupby().sum() to a find the top 10 industries that received the most funding, but I'm getting two rows of eCommerce with different 'Amount in USD' values, when it should just be one summed up row. How can I fix this?

Dataframe:

```
 Industries                         Amount in USD                      
 Transportation                     3.900000e+09                        
 **eCommerce**                      2.500000e+09                                           
 ECommerce                          1.400000e+09                                      
 **eCommerce**                      1.400000e+09                    
 FinTech                            1.000000e+09                       
 Online Marketplace                 7.000000e+08             
 E-Commerce & M-Commerce platform   6.800000e+08                        
 B2B                                5.850000e+08                        
 Car Aggregator & Retail Mobile App 5.000000e+08    
 Ecommerce Marketplace              5.000000e+08
```

Code:

```
ind = data.groupby(["Industries","Amount in USD"]).sum()


data = ind.sort_values("Amount in USD", ascending=False)


data1=data.head(10)

print(data1)
```

Comment: Please Try      ind = data.groupby("Industries")["Amount in USD"].sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### hard to see by the data by try:

```
ind = data.groupby(["Industries"]).agg({"Amount in USD":sum}).sort_values(by=["Amount in USD"], ascending = False).head(10)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I've now discovered another problem, where I have rows E-Commerce, ECommerce, and eCommerce in the top ten. Is there any way to sum those even though they're written differently? I'm very new to Pandas.

Comment: yes, you could convert them to the same value and than run the aggregation. Something like data['Indsutries']  = data['Industries'].str.lower().str.replace('-',''). str.replace('*','')  and than run the aggregation